# Creating a chat bubble using Shapes or 9-patch image

Tags: android, shapes, nine-patch

I am trying to create a template for my chat bubbles in an android app i am currently working on. The end result should look something like this:

[image]

I tried it with Shapes, but i could not get the multiple layers right. I also tried a 9-patch image, but creating the 9-patch was as far as i got. I hade no clue as to how to use it, specifically with the avatar, message header and content placements.

Can anyone help out?

My knowledge on shapes is fairly limited, although, i think i know just enough to understand what you guys will be saying :)

Comment: A 9 patch would be rally easy. Here's a nice tutorial: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/. Just have the extension being **.9.png**, not **.png**. Use it as a **background** for your TextView/s.

Comment: as you can see, there is a avatar and multiple text views for the header, time, and message.. that is where i struck out with 9-patch

Comment: If you have multiple Views in a ViewGroup... simply assign the background to the **ViewGroup** and you're good to go.

Comment: @DerGolem Am really sorry. I didn't see the comments and simply answered. I'm deleting my answer, please post your solution as an answer below.

Comment: never used ViewGroups before....  any examples?

Comment: @DustyRoberts [ViewGroups](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) are nothing but your collections of views. I'm sure you must have heard and used [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) and [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) before, these are but direct subclasses of ViewGroup.

Comment: @Antrromet ahh.... `RelativeLayout` will then do :) ... i was attemting a `<ViewGroup />`

Comment: A ViewGroup is a View container. That's really all: a "Group of Views".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 9 patch would be really easy. Here's a nice tutorial: [Simple Guide to 9 Patch](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).
Just make the extension **.9.png**, not just **.png**.
Use it as a background for your ViewGroup (your View container), as in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_left"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >
    <!-- The User -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
    <!-- The Date -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtUser"
    />
    <!-- The Message -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtDate"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I left you free to choose the graphics you desire (to match your taste and not to ruin your fun).

Obviously, you might want to prepare a bubble for the left side and a bubble for the right side (or have bubbles with differently coloured corners), and swap them accordingly in your Java code.

Comment: Your link is broken please update it..... Am looking for the same solution. Regards

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue I updated the link to point to the official docs. Radleymarx tutorial was really nicer, but they unfortunately removed the page.

Comment: Wow! Okay.. Thanks for replying

Comment: But have not seen any good tutorial teaching on 9 patch images from  scratch. Any recommendations???

Comment: Well, it's all about adding **black** markers (**1 px** wide) on the borders (the rest of the borders has to be **transparent**). Do this **after** scaling the image. Otherwise, the borders will be scaled as well. And, of course, choosing the right spots where to put the marker/s.