# Comments section like instagram for edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, instagram

I am trying to make the comments section the same as Instagram for edit text. My requirement is to show send as imeOptions with multiline typing and expanding the edit text.

This is what I tried, it starts typing in the next line but the edit text not expanding.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/etComment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="Add comment here..."
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/margin_100"
            android:maxLength="200"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: would probably be useful if you add an image to show what you're looking for - not everyone uses instagram :)

Comment: if i get it correct then you can check 9.png formate  like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506117/creating-a-chat-bubble-using-shapes-or-9-patch-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is nearby correct. Please add inputType = 'text' as well.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/etComment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="Add comment here..."
            android:inputType="text|textCapSentences"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/margin_100"
            android:maxLength="200"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Also, in activity class

```
etComment.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
etComment.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Let me know, if that works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to catch text change and change the height manually according the number of lines entered by user for expanding or sharing

Comment: Are you this will be the only solution? I am expecting to do it by XML only.

Comment: text input is different from textview it can't be enlarged according to content